# How to update range of columns in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, find-and-replace

I have an excel sheet where from one sheets's Id used as reference in next sheet.
The Id's are sequential. Like this :

```
Sheet 1             Sheet 2     

ID  Name            ID  Sheet_1_ID  Text
1   ABC              1      1       asd
2   XYZ              2      2       dsa
3   PQR              3      2       sadas
4   LMN              4      3       asdas
                     5      3       asd
                     6      4       asd
```

Now for some reason I want to change some of the ID's from Sheet 1 and want to be replaced in sheet 2. So basically I have list like :

```
OldID NewID  
1      23
2      24
3      25
4      26
```

The only way I can found is to use find n replace feature of excel, but its a lot of time consuming.

Is there any formula,script or small piece of code which can do to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the OldIDs are unique, add in a helper column to each sheet with the following (assumes OldID/NewID list is on Sheet3, with OldIDs in column A and NewIDs in column B, and OldIDs on the current sheet are in column A starting at row 2):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Effectively, this translates to: "Take the value in A2 on the current sheet, find it in the left-most column of A:B on Sheet3, and bring back the matching value in the second column of A:B on Sheet3". The FALSE parameter specifies only to accept data where an *exact match* is found for A2. (Counterintuitive, yes.)

Once that's set for row 2, copy it down the rest of the sheet. After you've spot-checked to make sure this is working right, you can just copy the imported data and use "Paste Values" to overwrite the IDs column.

Comment: Its working but not all the columns are referenced using VLookup(A2) like ... they are just copied from the cells above from them they are not being replaced

Comment: The point is to use the VLOOKUP column to pull in the NewIDs, and then copy/paste it (using Paste Values) to do the replacement.